# Model binding a list on a complex type in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble with model binding in ASP.NET Core MVC. I have this endpoint, which gets hit when called from Javascript, but the postData is always null.

```
    [HttpPost("/somepost")]
    public string SomePost([FromBody] PostData postData)
    {
        return "Got It!";
    }

    public class PostData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string[] ListOrArray { get; set; } // Doesn't matter if this ends up a List or an Array
    }
```

This endpoint is being hit from a $.click function:

```
$('img.some-image').click(function () {
    array = ['sample data', 'some more'];

    data = {
        ID: 1,
        ListOrArray: array 
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/somepost',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Received: ');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm guessing that the problem is model binding, but I am not sure. I've seen examples with lowercase Javascript object property names, but that didn't change anything for me.

I also have to remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the POST, but I would prefer adding it back in. I'm guessing that I would have to add the token to the GET request so that I could submit it for the POST, but I haven't figured out how to do that. I don't think that has anything to do with my problem though.

I've searched for answers and examples, but none of them have worked for me. ASP.NET Core is pretty new so there isn't much out there. I am on version 1.1.0.

Comment: To add the token, just include `__RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();` in your 'data object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `contentType:json` but you are sending a `plain object` you need to send `json object`.

To convert your `object` to `json object` you can use `JSON.stringify`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/somepost',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
      console.log('Received: ');
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Comment: `datatype` has nothing to do with what is posted (that specifies the type that the server sends back). I assume you meant to say _You have set `contentType: 'json`' but ..._

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes exactly.